# Directory Overriding on Wordpress

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In WordPress, I have a page called `Experiments` with a slug of `experiments`. That page should be able to be accessed at `http://site.com/experiments`.

Problem is, I also want to have a folder on my server with that name so that `http://site.com/experiments/thing/` loads the `index.html` file of the folder (if there is one).

I thought I had found the perfect rewrite structure (from [this blog post](http://striderweb.com/nerdaphernalia/2008/03/override-single-wordpress-pages-with-htaccess/)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.htm !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

It looks like it rewrites directories using WordPress unless the directory has an index.html or index.php file in which case it loads it ignoring WordPress. And it works perfectly for subdirectories, but `http://site.com/experiments/` tries to redirect to `http://site.com/experiments` back and forth forever.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Wordpress wasn't adding trailing slashes to items, so it was sending me to `/experiments` and then Apache wanted to send me back to `/experiments/` resulting in a loop.

Did a ton of reading on URLs (which was very interesting/fun) and now have decided to add trailing slashes to all my URLs. And everything is working perfectly.

Edit: An interesting side note is that Wordpress decides whether to use trailings slashes everywhere based on whether there is one in your custom permalink structure (ie. `/%postname%/`). Wasted a good amount of time searching as to where I set that, and it was right there all along.